# Algorithm to decide if giving rest is possible

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Inputs:
coins (value:amount pairs), amount to change

Output: True or False

For example:

```
Input = {50:4, 100:1, 200:2}, 300  (I have 4 pieces of '50', 1 pieces of '100' etc), must give 300 back
Output = True
```

This example is dumb. Coins could have different values like odd values.

Coins can't have decimal values.

Any leads?

Pseudo code is ok

Python is also ok (preferred, but not so important)

EDIT:

I'm asking for leads, not for complete code. I was thinking about a 'brute force' approach: generate all possible combinations and check each of them against the amount of coins i have. But it doesn't seem clever to me..

Haven't you got better ideas on how to proceed?

Another example could be:

```
Input = {3:2, 7:1, 10:1}, 15
Output = False
```

Comment: ...we _don't write code for you_. Show what you've tried first and where you're stuck.

Comment: If you think the example is dumb, provide a better example, along with your code.

Comment: @ForceBru   edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is a SAT algorithm and it has an exponential complexity, therefore unless you have some extra constraints you must do an exhaustive check (brute force as you said).

You may be interested in the function `itertools.combinations(iterable, combinations_length)` to sum all possible combinations. also you can represent your elements like this: `{3:2, 7:1, 10:1}` => `[3, 3, 7, 10]`

You can check this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem
for other options